# Send file attachment with outgoing webhook in Slack

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api, ifttt

I want to upload any file that is uploaded in slack channel to the linked google drive account. So as and when a user uploads a file in slack channel, that file should get uploaded in Google Drive also.
I am thinking of using slack outgoing web hooks to do this.Is it possible with web hooks or should I try any other approach like create custom app in slack?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using an [ougoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks). It's an outdated legacy feature, which currently only exists for backward compatibility of older apps. But may be removed in the future.

This is from the official Slack webpage:

> You're reading this because you're looking for info on legacy custom
>   integrations - an outdated way for teams to integrate with Slack.
>   These integrations lack newer features and they will be deprecated and
>   possibly removed in the future. We do not recommend their use.

Instead create your own Slack App and use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). With the events app Slack will automatically send a request to your app once a message has been posted to channel (which would include file uploads). Your app can then filter out the relevant messages (e.g. google file uploads) and upload those files to Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Can you help me with any resources or similar code for making a slack app which can filter uploads on slack channel?